# Test Automation Using Selenium for Microservices Architecture

Tags: selenium, automation

I am in charge of implementing QA processes and test automation for a project using microservices architecture.

I am going to use Selenium with Java. I am new to Selenium.

In this project using microservices architecture, we have to test each module in isolation so that each module in itself is meaninful. I will be assinging QA's to test each module as a team seperately. Now my question is do we have to build framework for each module for automation?

I am going to get an experiensed automation engineer to help me out with framework but I have to have my strategy and planning before hand .

It is going to be implemented using RESTFUL API'S. I have implemented manual  testing on the same product in monolith architecture but this is now completely new experience for me and on that I have another new experience with automation.

Can anyone help me out or suggest me good resources which can help me understand and build the strategy for test and also for automation. 
I'm not sure at which stage of project we can start implementation for automation?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you reformulate your question to make it less verbose and more relevant? I can't get how selenium is relevant to your question?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Selenium is relevant to this question as I'm going to use selenium as an automation tool. I know its broader question. Can you also please ignore the part --- Project has one public api till--- repo for selenium tests ... I was unable to edit and delete this part. I think you are confused by this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a test strategy in a single post would not be feasible, but will try to point out the major parts that you can start from. I have used [this as a foundation](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/) in one of my previous teams:

*Testing Strategies in a Microservice Architecture*
[image: msoa]

Selenium tests will fit in the E2E tests, be sure to keep those as much focused and quick as possible. You really need just a few of those journeys.

[Meta-frameworks](http://automationisking.blogspot.bg/2015/01/enterprise-meta-api-test-framework.html) are a good fit. You don't want to duplicate code, just pack the common [harness libs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) and share it between the service level tests.